# Show the jQuery result on other textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I use this jQuery function to remove html tags. But it works in the same textarea. I want to show result in another textarea.

Here is Example

```js
function removeHTMLTags() {
        $('#data').val(function (i, val) {
            return $('<div>').html(val).text();
        });

    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="text" onclick="removeHTMLTags();">Click</button>
<br>
Source:
<br>
<textarea id="data"><b>Hello</b></textarea>
<br>
Result
<br>
<textarea id="result"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of setting the value to the same textarea, set it to the result `textarea`

```js
function removeHTMLTags() {
  var val = $('#data').val();
  $('#result').val($('<div>').html(val).text())

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="text" onclick="removeHTMLTags();">Click</button>
<br>Source:
<br>
<textarea id="data"><b>Hello</b>
</textarea>
<br>Result
<br>
<textarea id="result"></textarea>
```